# Changing object type to instance of child class in Swift

Tags: arrays, object, swift, types

Array contains shapes and named shapes objects. Shape is a parent for named shape and only difference is name property.

When user want to give name to shape. Object of type shape suppose to be converted to type named shape.

How do I do it using swift and is it proper thing to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just cast the object to the needed type:

```
if let namedShape = shape as? NamedShape {
    // do sth.
}
```

The condition tries to cast the shape object to the class "NamedShape". If this works, the block is executed.

Comment: it's not casting for my case, so code never runs inside if

Comment: Are you sure, the object is the correct class? There is also the keyword "is", which only checks if an object is a specific class without casting it:   if shape is NamedShape { ... }

Comment: I used your if and just add "else" in case object is type of Shape and not casting. So another code in else block works perfect for me. Thank you freytag!